# No obtengo los datos de $http GET en Angular

Tags: angularjs

No muestra la página al intentar realizar el GET. Tengo el siguiente codigo:

app.js

```js
(function(){
    var app= angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

app.controller('NotiCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.posts=[];
    $http.get('http://www.notilogia.com/wp-json')
      .success(function(data){
        console.log(data.data.children);
        $scope.posts=data.data.children;

      });
      

  });
    
    
app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
} ());
```

En index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="NotiCtrl">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Notilogia</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
      <div class="list">
          
          <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="post in posts" href="{{post.data.url}}">
        <img ng-src="{{post.data.thumbnail}}"ng-if="post.data.thumbnail.indexOf('http')===0">
          <h2 class="post-title">{{post.data.title}}</h2>
          <p>{{post.data.domain}}</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>﻿
```

Comment: Revisa la consola y mira que error te pone. Edita la pregunta y agrega esa información para poder entender cual es el problema.

Comment: Lo estoy realizando desde ionic, por ende no trae consola.

Comment: Las aplicaciones de ionic pueden probarse en un navegador y también desde un dispositivo android. Lee http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/. Sin saber que error te da es imposible darle solución a tu problema.

Comment: En tu html te no veo la libreria de angular https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la respuesta del GET del servicio al que llamas está mal formada y no puede ser parseada por angularjs a JSON.
Haciendo un poco de debugging noté que la respuesta viene de la siguiente forma:

```
<script>
        var url = "http://www.notilogia.com/";

    </script>
    {"name":"Notilog\u00eda","description":"Te ofrece m\u00e1s que noticias.","url":"http:\/\/www.notilogia.com","home":"http:\/\/www.notilogia.com","namespaces":["oembed\/1.0","wp\/v2"],"authentication":[],"routes":{...}
```

**Nota: La respuesta del servicio está cortada por motivo de restricción de respuesta en SO**

Mi única recomendación sería el transformar la respuesta e ir quitando un poco de los caracteres que no cumplen con el formato JSON.
**OJO: Siempre y cuando estés seguro que solo estos caracteres son los que sobran**
Por ejemplo:

```
$http.get('http://www.notilogia.com/wp-json', {
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                return JSON.parse(data.replace('<script>', '').replace('var url = "http://www.notilogia.com/";', '').replace("<\script>", ''));
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.posts = response.data;
        });
```

Tambien noté que esperas **data.childrens**. Este elemento no existe en la respuesta, por lo que te recomiendo que la examines para elegir el dato que quieres mostrar en **$scope.posts**